# iOS GET Request with a cookie

Tags: ios, session, nsurlrequest

I'm trying to send an HTTP GET request in order to load some data, and I'm only now realizing that it is completely different than a POST request. I am not entirely sure how I am supposed to construct the entire GET request. Additionally, I am being troubled because I need to add a cookie containing a string that is a user's session ID to the GET request.

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?  Some information on the url you are trying to construct?  The framework you are using?  Have you done any research on how cookies are sent in a http request?